How to handle excessive self pity
Sometimes my 11 year-old child will fall to excessive self pity. Two examples:
He was very angry about something and tossed away his phone, a corner of the phone cracked and he thought he had broken it completely and permanently. I heard him wailing from the street 200 meters away. I thought something terrible had happed, like maybe he fell and seriously injured himself. His frustration is perfectly understandable: he was already frustrated and then he lost his temper and thought he broke his favourite and most expensive play-thing. But he actively fuels the fire, the crying goes on when all the tears are spent, in a theatrical manner. He throws himself on the couch, grinds his teeth, balls his fists.
Another example: The teacher gaves us exercises to practice writing and spelling at home to help speed up his writing. He hates doing this because its school-work outside school and unlike regular homework this is not something the whole class has to do. He procastrinates, laments how unfair it is he has to do this while his friends don't, then claims he cannot spell and will do everything wrong anyway. He then cries, holds the pencil limply in his hand. While focussing on making a theater and arguing with parents he will make silly mistakes, like not finishing a word or forgetting letters, this fuels more crying and 'see I can't do this'. Last time he was hitting himself in the head with both fists after spending almost 1 hour on writing down two sentences and 5 words.
Again, this is a frustrating situation, but he is making it so much worse. The task is intended to last 15 minutes.
I understand I should avoid these situations and help him deal with frustrations but sometimes frustrating things happen. I have read 'How to talk to kids' and I try not to tell him off for his feelings, but I do want him to stop fanning the flames of negative emotions.

@Ivana - I'd like to suggest something based on: underdeveloped fine motor skills, difficulty with impulse control, easily frustrated (?), and emotionally somewhat volatile. To me, these things add up to a red flag for neurodivergence. Has he ever been tested? If not, it's probably the wisest and best thing you can do for him and yourself/the family. If he is neuroatypical, specialists can help guide you in how to respond, can help him to learn about why he acts out and how to mitigate that, and all of you to understand where this behavior is coming from. Please consider this.

I am not a specialist, but I can tell you what I've done with my children in this situation (and they are now older and seem to have turned out OK :))

Don't chastise him for his outbursts, deny or contradict his feelings or raise your own voice in response. Stay calm (I know it's easier said than done) and don't really engage with the outburst.
For the homework situation, just repeat something bland like "Yes, I know, it's frustrating isn't it, I understand you feel angry, I would feel sad and cross too. But the teachers know best how to help us, so we do need to do this homework now, so let's just get it done. Would you like a hug first, or a drink of water, and then we'll get on with it?" For my children, very often a hug - showing them I love them despite the outburst, and letting them choose when to end the hug - was often enough to then let them engage positively.
For the broken phone situation, again, repeat something bland like "It's normal to feel sad and cross when something like this happens, that bad feeling is part of the way that our brains try to help us remember not do something like this again - so let's take that bad feeling and use it next time to make a different choice".
If something is only supposed to take 15 minutes then limit it to 15 minutes. If that's 15 minutes of outburst and 1 sentence written instead of 10, so be it. But to my mind, it doesn't benefit anyone to spend an hour wailing and gnashing teeth, and if the teacher knew that was what was happening, he or she wouldn't want you to force the issue. You can always write an email explaining to the teacher what happened.

The general idea is to give space for the emotions but also not exacerbate them, just help the child to accept them and move on from them.

"The general idea is to give space for the emotions but also not exacerbate them, just help the child to accept them and move on from them." This is the lesson I take from the 'How to talk to children ...' book, but in my examples there is really no excuse for self-pity. For anger and frustrations yes, but not self-pity.

This is a great answer!

@Ivana - Self-pity is an emotion, too. It's a kind of grief or sorrow,  allowing someone to validate their prior negative feelings (negative in that they are not positive feelings like joy or accomplishment). It often reflects a need for validation The more you fight/invalidate his self-pity, the more he actually needs/earned it. This is a good answer.
